# how to put script to angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-cli

I have some project on Angular CLI. So I need to put some scripts to a component but it seems they arent there

my code in the component:

```
    <script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="login_button" ></div>
<script language="javascript ">
    VK.init({
      apiId: 6241489
    });
    /*function authInfo(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        alert('user: '+response.session.mid);
        } else {
        alert('not auth');
        }
    }
    VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);*/
    VK.UI.button('login_button');
    </script>
```

Who know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the third-party script by adding it to the `apps[0].scripts` property in `.angular-cli.json` as described in [Angular CLI doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).

Then, make the global `VK` object accessible in your component by definining `declare var VK: any;` and call `VK.init()` from your component's `ngOnInit()`. I assume that will be the AppComponent.

Comment: @tatamingi Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark under the counter at the left

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you're supposed to create script tags in your component.html files.

If you want to fire the supposed function, try this.

.ts file:

```
authInfo() {
    // Where does response params come from?
    if (response.session) {
        alert('user: '+response.session.mid);
    } else {
        alert('not auth');
    }
}
```

.html template:

```
<button (click)="authInfo()"></button>
```

Please reply to this answer with more detail so I can assist you further :)